# C# - How to designate an enum as must be implemented in abstract class?

Tags: c#, enums, factory

For example, I have a factory class:

```
abstract class UnitFactory<T> where T:Unit
{
   abstract enum UnitType;

   public abstract T GetUnit(UnitType type);
}
```

Here, the derived class **must** have a enum (of course `abstract enum` doesn't work) to indicate which kind of unit it can make, instead of a bunch of string consts which I think is hard to enforce/manage.

So my question is how do I make an *"abstract"* enum like this? Or if it's not possible, what is the best practice to do something similar?

Sorry for my bad English and my seemingly stupid question.

Edit:
Sample child class:

```
class ArcherFactory : UnitFactory<Archer>
{
   private static Archer _baseLongbowman = ....;
   private static Archer _baseCrossbowman = ....;

   // Child class must have a implementation of UnitType enum to
   // tell the user that it can only make those kind of units.
   public enum UnitType{ Longbowman, Crossbowman }

   public override Archer getUnit(UnitType type)
   {
      if (type == UnitType.Longbowman) return _baseLongbowman.Clone(...);
      return _baseCrossbowman.Clone(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: What does `abstract enum` mean? Enums do not support inheritance. They are just values

Comment: enum is a value type, sadly thus you can't derive anything from it

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Having a problem with X, assuming Y is the solution (abstract enums) and when that doesn't work, asking for Y, not the actual problem X. What is the actual problem ?

Comment: I understand, I just want to have something like an "abstract enum", a must be implemented enum.

Comment: @Tr1et: what is an "implemented enum"? Provide an example of how you would 1) instantiate several concrete factories and 2) call `GetUnit` for several combinations of factories/unit types.

Comment: That just doesn't exist though. As Panagiotis says, you should give us more information about what you're actually trying to achieve, rather than just the solution you thought you were going to implement.

Comment: Given that an enum doesn't need implementing, what is the *actual* problem behind this?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I just added a example.

Comment: You can't enforce this through the compiler. There is nothing stopping me from just reusing an existing enum or something else defined elsewhere. Why do you see the need to try to enforce this? You can define unit-tests that use reflection to go look for that enum but it's going to be difficult to enforce the *usage* of it even so.

Comment: Have you considered using extensions methods for the enum? Your function `getUnit` looks a little bit like an extension method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In my game, there will be more factory which just spawn Units with the same class but different inner data, so I though I can have a abstract factory to use as Component in spawners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define two generic types for your abstract factory

```
public abstract class UnitFactory<TType, TUnit> where TUnit:Unit
{
    public abstract TUnit GetUnit(TType type);
}
```

And then you need to expose the archer type outside your archer factory, otherwise it would not be usable.

```
public enum ArcherType { Longbowman, Crossbowman }
```

And eventually create the archer factory.

```
public class ArcherFactory : UnitFactory<ArcherType, Archer>
{
    private static Archer _baseLongbowman = ....;
    private static Archer _baseCrossbowman = ....;

    public override Archer GetUnit(ArcherType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ArcherType.Crossbowman:
                return  _baseCrossbowman.Clone(...);

            default:
                return  _baseLongbowman.Clone(...);

        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Instead using your static instances and cloning you could use Func to create your separate instances of each unit.

```
public class ArcherFactory : UnitFactory<ArcherType, Archer>
{
    public ArcherFactory()
    {
        this.Register(ArcherType.Longbowman, () => new Archer(...));
        this.Register(ArcherType.Crossbowman, () => new Archer(...));
    }
}

public abstract class UnitFactory<TType, TUnit>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TType, Func<TUnit>> factoryMethods = new Dictionary<TType, Func<TUnit>>();

    protected void Register(TType type, Func<TUnit> constructorFuc)
    {
        // perform some sanity checks
        this.factoryMethods.Add(type, constructorFuc);
    }

    public TUnit GetUnit(TType type)
    {
        // perform some sanity checks
        return this.factoryMethods[type]();
    }
}
```

And use that

```
var archerFactory = new ArcherFactory();
var crossbowMan = archerFactory.GetUnit(ArcherType.Crossbowman);
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!! I really didn't think about passing enum as type parameter. But can I restrict first type parameter to be enum?

Comment: Though you should be fine with just one UnitType enum and registering different constructor delegates to just 1 factory with different enum values... so could just use UnitFactory.Create(UnitType.LongBowman). No need for cloning etc either.

Comment: Added example of registering funcs within the factory which will make your life easier without worrying about cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Requiring each concrete factory to expose its own list of types means all concrete implementations will be tied to that factory alone.

In other words, there is absolutely **no benefit** in doing:

```
var longbowman = archerFactory.GetUnit(ArcherFactory.UnitType.Longbowman);
var crossbowman = archerFactory.GetUnit(ArcherFactory.UnitType.Crossbowman);
```

compared to simply:

```
// this is better than a huge switch/case method
var longbowman = archerFactory.GetLongbowman()
var crossbowman  = archerFactory.GetCrossbowman();
```

For the abstract factory pattern to make sense, you need to have the type defined separately from the factory, i.e.

```
enum ArcherType { Longbowman, Crossbowman }

interface IFactory<Ttype, Tvalue>
{
    Tvalue GetUnit(Ttype);
}

interface IArcherFactory : IFactory<ArcherType, Archer>
{
    ...
}
```